# .gitignore wildcard suffix exclusion with negation for subfolder

Tags: git, wildcard, gitignore, subdirectory, negation

I have a .gitignore which is like this:

```
*.png
*.jpg
*.gif
!0/*.png
!0/*.jpg
!0/*.gif
```

I want to ignore all image files (.png, .jpg, .gif) in all folders but not in the folder `/0/`. All image files in this folder should not be ignored.

I tried with the above .ignore file but it is not working as image files in `/0/` are still ignored. How to write this correctly?

Comment: Do you mean `./0/` directory? I mean, not an absolute path as `/0/`

Comment: The subdirectory has the name of 0. All images within the folder zero should not be excluded. Maybe its just trivial but I did not figure out the correct way of writing it after several tries.

Comment: Is .gitignore a "use first match" system? Try putting the negated lines first.

Comment: Tried but does not help. `!0/` would work by the way but thats not what I need here.

Comment: Could you add your actual directory structure to the original question? (i.e: `tree` or `ls -al . 0` )

Comment: Hmm there are many many nested subfolders in 0/ and there are also many many folders in the root directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ignore pattern:

```
!0/*.png
```

means "don't ignore any `*.png` file that is *directly* inside a folder named 0". So this would include `0/abc.png`, and it would include `1/0/def.png`, but it would exclude `0/1/ghi.png`.

If you want to include all `*.png` below the folder 0, there are two ways to do this.

You can use the following pattern:

```
*.png
!/0/**/*.png
```

The `**` pattern matches any series of subdirectories, including the root. Starting the pattern with `/` means that the pattern must match starting with the current directory. 
So this will include `0/abc.png`, `0/subdir/def.png`, and `0/subdir/ghi/jkl.png`. It will exclude `abc.png` and `1/abc.png`.

Alternatively, you can create a file `.gitignore` with

```
*.png
```

And then you can create another file, `0/.gitignore`, which contains:

```
!*.png
```

This is a little more obvious, and it has exactly the same effect.

### Demo

Here is the base `*.png` rule, it ignores all `*.png` files:

```
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in .../.git/
$ mkdir -p 0/1
$ touch img.png 0/img.png 0/1/img.png
$ cat >.gitignore
*.png
$ git add -n .
add '.gitignore'
```

Here is the rule you have, which includes any `*.png` inside any directory named `0`:

```
$ cat >.gitignore
*.png
!0/*.png
$ git add -n .
add '.gitignore'
add '0/img.png'
```

Here is the fixed pattern:

```
$ cat >.gitignore  
*.png
!/0/**/*.png
$ git add -n .
add '.gitignore'
add '0/1/img.png'
add '0/img.png'
```

Here is the alternative:

```
$ cat >.gitignore
*.png
$ cat >0/.gitignore
!*.png
$ git add -n .
add '.gitignore'
add '0/.gitignore'
add '0/1/img.png'
add '0/img.png'
```